# Creating a list that shows the numerical values not in boolean form

Tags: list-manipulation

Based from the equation I used in the code below, I found how many values are divisible by 5. However, this is in boolean form. I only know how many are divisible by 5 which is 7500. I need to formulate a conjecture by exploring the values, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a list that gives me all the true 7500 numerical values that are divisible by 5 based from given function. Here's is my program.

```
expn = Flatten[Table[1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n, {n, 1, 10000}]];
sumpowern = Mod[Total /@ expn, 5] ;
Count[sumpowern, 0]
posints = Length[Select[Divisible[Total /@ expn , 5], TrueQ]]
```

Comment: `Pick[expn, Thread[sumpowern == 0]]`

Comment: No, this just shows all 10000 values, I just want the 7500 values that were found divisible by 5

Comment: `Pick[expn, Mod[expn, 5], 0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["`*"];
f[n_ /; n ∈ PositiveIntegers] := 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n;
test[n_] := TrueQ[Mod[f[n], 5] == 0];
Select[Range[10000], test]
```